# Why did Savage Opress's amulet keep going out?

Tags: star-wars, the-clone-wars

In the *Star Wars: The Clone Wars* episode "Brothers", Savage Opress travels to the planet Lotho Minor in search of his long-lost brother. He's guided by an amulet given to him by Mother Talzin, that glows brighter the closer he is to his brother.

On three separate occasions, the amulet temporarily stops glowing: once while he is flying over Lotho Minor, once shortly after he lands, and once shortly after he enters the entrance to his brother's lair. On the third occasion, Savage believes Mother Talzin has betrayed him, but once he enters the depths of the lair, the amulet starts glowing again, and sure enough, he finds his brother alive.

While it's hard to tell with Mother Talzin, I don't believe she betrayed Savage (if she did, the amulet wouldn't have turned back on again). But that begs the question: **why *did* it keep going out?** Was its magic running dry? Was it like a "you have reached your destination" thing? What was going on there?

Comment: We don't know how the amulet works. I think that it has something to do with The Force.  When I watched that, I presumed there are "dead zones", places where The Force is weaker.  Or, like cell phone, no reception zones. There are certainly the opposite places, where The Force is stronger. Often, temples are built on those sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have any official confirmation for this, but the amulet going out can be interpreted as the upcoming "change in course". The amulet is magical enough to know when Savage needs to be guided and when he needs to stop and look for guidance from someone else.

On three separate occasions the amulet sends some kind of a message to Savage:

- When he's flying other Lotho Minor, the amulet goes out exactly over Maul's location. This means that Savage needs to stop playing the hotter/colder game and land on the surface.
- On the surface, the amulet goes out again just before he meets Morley. The message is that he can't find a safe way to the lair himself and needs a local guide.
- The amulet goes out the third time just before Savage is betrayed by Morley. Again, the amulet puts him exactly in a position where he can conveniently be sent down into the caves.

All in all, the amulet is not a proximity sensor, not a technological device. The fact that it stops working doesn't mean it malfunctioned. It's a magical artifact that stops exactly when it needs to stop.

Comment: I've just finished watching the *Rebels* episode "Twin Suns", where Ezra tracks down Obi-Wan using pieces of a holocron, and the exact same thing happened: when Ezra's A-Wing was directly over Obi-Wan's location, the pieces stopped glowing. I'm therefore convinced that your answer is correct.